# Не срабатывает скрипт jQuery

Tags: jquery, скрипт, html, javascript

Для списка объектов

```
<div class='view-source'>
    <h3><a href="#" class="click">Магнитные барабаны</a></h3>
        <div class="hide">
            <ul>
                       <li>...</li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
</div>

<div class='view-source'>
    <h3><a href="#" class="click">Магнитные плиты </a></h3>
        <div class="hide">
            <ul>
                       <li>...</li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
</div>

<div class='view-source'>
    <h3><a href="#" class="click">Магнитные решетки</a></h3>
        <div class="hide">
            <ul>
                       <li>...</li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

пишется скрипт, чтобы по щелчку на ссылке открывался список под конкретной ссылкой

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Раскрывающийся список
    $(".view-source .hide").hide();
    $(".view-source a.click").toggle(
     function(){
        $(this).siblings('.hide').stop(false, true).slideDown(500);
       }, 
     function(){
        $(this).siblings('.hide').stop(false, true).slideUp(500);
     });
}); 
</script>
```

Но он не срабатывает, списки не открываются вообще. Подскажите, что неправильно?

Answer (score 3):

`siblings('.hide')`, вызванная от `a.click`, вернёт пустой набор, вызывать `siblings` надо от родительского узла `a.click`.

Comment: а код привести можете? а то я не совсем понимаю.

Comment: $(this).parent().siblings('.hide') или  $(this).parent().next('.hide')

Comment: @iKuzko спасибо.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.view-source .hide').hide();

$('a.click').bind('click',function(){

    $(this).parent().parent().find('.hide').toggle();
});
```

Comment: не срабатывает, все списки отображаются в развернутом виде =(

Comment: только используйте способ тов. @iKuzko он более приемлем [http://jsfiddle.net/bbZzf/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/bbZzf/2/)

Comment: я уже сделала совсем другим способом.